# Spam mail from unknown gmail address

Tags: email, exchange, email-server

My organization have our own exchange server for mail communications. Recently someone from outside creates gmail accounts in the name of our employees and sending unwanted communications to our employees. Is there any configurations/services that can be used to avoid this ? We have blocked all such email addresses in the firewall but the sender is creating email addresses.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Any updates? Does above suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a transport rule to block Gmail account, the rule likes this：
[image]

Note： the rule will block all gmail accounts to send mails to your organization.